# ESP8266 RF Calibration

Tags: esp8266, arduino-uno-wifi

As an off-Topic to my main [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78808/robotdyns-unowifi-r3-atmega328pesp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb?noredirect=1#comment174934_78808), regarding Robodyn's Uno+Wifi - it seems that Wifi does not work ( fail to connect and fail find any network ).

Juraj advised to use External Antenna ( did not work ) and try to make an RF calibration as shown [on espressif's site](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/espressif-esp-faq/en/latest/development-environment/debugging.html?highlight=calibration#how-can-i-modify-the-default-method-of-rf-calibration-in-esp8266). Which I fail to understand how it is done.

a) Can anyone help with RF Calibration ?

b) Might it be another reason for that ?

Guy

**EDIT_1**
Just to be clear, a sלetch was uploaded and executed successfully to the ESP8266 module (Basic WiFi connect and network scan ).

**Edit_2**
[image: close up pic]

Comment: Every ESP8266 schematic I can find has a 5.6pF capacitor between the LNA pin and the antenna. Robotdyn's doesn't - it has a resistor. Looks like they aren't that great at designing RF circuits...

Comment: @Majenko - So by definition it has no WiFi ? Can it be fixed ?

Comment: I'm not so sure. I'm going by the schematics here, but they don't seem to match what I am seeing in the product image. What I *think* is R13 looks to actually be a capacitor... It looks like there's no real relation between the published schematics and what is really on the board.

Comment: @Majenko - See Edit1 please ( to be sure )

Comment: Yeah, I had been following your original question.

Comment: I think the schematics were drawn by a child. They haven't even got any component values on them...! They're useless.

Comment: @Majenko - it could have been funnier if I hadn't purchased it :). 
Do you know what might be the drivers for ? under "Documents" tab on their site

Comment: They'll be for the CH340G.

Comment: Have you closely inspected the soldering of the ESP8266 chip on your board?

Comment: I'm using linux - that I could find ( that it belong to CH340 ). But under Windows, it actually have an exe file

Comment: @Majenko see pic. Don’t see anything suspicious

Comment: Ok, looking at that I can tell you that there is a capacitor fitted to connect the LNA to the u.FL connector. What value that capacitor is I can't say. There is no capacitor fitted to use the PCB antenna. So you *must* use an external antenna (make sure it's a 2.45GHz one) or modify the board.

Comment: Looking at the colour of that capacitor for the u.FL it looks way higher than 5.6pF. More like 1nF.

Comment: @Majenko - I took it from `Wemos D1 mini Pro` I guess it is what needed. As said - with or without  the antenna, I get nothing.

Comment: I'd be inclined to removed the u.FL capacitor and solder in a known 5.6pF into the PCB antenna capacitor footprint.

Comment: I would try to upload AT firmware. forum users reported QOUT setting for flash

Comment: @Juraj - how can I do that ?

Comment: https://blog.gabrielcsapo.com/arduino-web-server-mega-2560-r3-built-in-esp8266/

Comment: @Juraj - Excellent reference!!

Comment: it has some problems, the author didn't want to change. he wrote it based on a forum session with me. you can download the AT firmware 1.7.4 here https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14

Comment: @Juraj UPDATE: using the blog, each step was done successfuly, incl. downloading the firmware as you pointed, yielded the same result ( using ext. antenna ). :(((((  - while my basic check is network scan ( no networks found ). what can I do more. ??

Comment: so return the board or you could try the hardware fix recommended by Majenko

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything else with the RF calibration then to clean the flash area where it is stored. There are two reason for doing it:

First is reason to delete the RF calibration area is, if it was written by different version of Espressif SDK, including changing between AT firmware and Arduino. Then it is almost always wrong. I think they changed the data structure so some values are swapped.

Second reason is if the SDK did the calibration in wrong conditions like without antenna.

There is not much information about RF calibration. The [FAQ](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/espressif-esp-faq/en/latest/development-environment/debugging.html?highlight=calibration#how-can-i-modify-the-default-method-of-rf-calibration-in-esp8266) has "Please erase the RF parameters to trigger overall calibration."

The AT firmware reference has (addresses for 4MB-C1):

- blank.bin 0x3FB000 Initializes RF_CAL parameter area.
- esp_init_data_default.bin 0x3FC000 Stores default RF parameter values, has to be downloaded into flash at least once. If the RF_CAL parameter area is initialized, this bin has to be downloaded too

The esp8266 Arduino core writes the data of esp_init_data_default.bin as part of the sketch's binary.

EDIT: the SDK does the 'digital calibration' at boot. it takes some microseconds. it is not done at every boot, but after some count of resets. this can be configured in the init section

Comment: Thank you again. From FAQ, I don't have any operative steps what to do.

Comment: flash blank.bin to 0x3FB000  or erase the entire flash.

Comment: Erasing using `esptool.py` ? since erasing using Arduino IDE did not solve it

Comment: Arduino IDE uses esptool.py. btw. what are your Tools menu settings?

Comment: Right... silly me. I'm setting `Generic ESP8266 Module`... now when I'm thinkg of it - the default is 1MB. Is that what you ment ?

Comment: set 4 MB end try to erase the flash again. but I think the esptool.py is not fooled with the setting when it executes the erase

Comment: Nope - setting to 4MB, nor to `Wifi Arduino` under `ESP8266` didn't make it :(